# Cannot signal after peer is destroyed . Simple-peer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, webrtc, simple-peer

I'm a beginner in webrtc . I have used simple-peer to connect two peers on a video calling application .
When a second peer is connected , his video is displayed but after a few seconds an error showing "cannot signal when peer is destroyed" is thrown . I dont know where I'm going wrong . I have attached the code below .

The code error is thrown in this line :

```
PeerRef.current.signal(signal);
```

client.js :

```
import React, { useEffect,useRef } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
`;

const LeftRow = styled.div`
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
`;

const RightRow = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
`;

const Video = styled.video`
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
`;

const Room=(props)=>{
    const socketRef=useRef();
    const userRef=useRef();
    const partnerRef=useRef();
    const PeerRef=useRef();
    

    useEffect(()=>{
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true}).then((stream)=>{
                userRef.current.srcObject=stream;
                
                socketRef.current=io.connect('/');
                console.log("hello");
                console.log(props.match.params.roomID);
                socketRef.current.emit("join room",props.match.params.roomID);
                
                socketRef.current.on("other user",(PartnerID)=>{
                    console.log("creator");
                    if(PartnerID){
                        console.log("partner");
                        PeerRef.current=createPeer(PartnerID,socketRef.current.id,stream);
                    }
                });
                socketRef.current.on("caller signal",(incoming)=>{
                    console.log("Caller signal from browser");
                    PeerRef.current=addPeer(incoming.CallerID,incoming.signal,stream);
                    
                });
                socketRef.current.on("callee signal",(signal)=>{
                    console.log("callee signal from browser"); 
                      
                    PeerRef.current.signal(signal);
                });

        })
        

    },[]);
    
    function handleStream(stream){
        partnerRef.current.srcObject=stream;
        
    }
    const createPeer = (PartnerID,CallerID,stream) =>{
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator:true,
            trickle:false,
            stream
        });
        peer.on("signal",(signal)=>{
            const payload={
                PartnerID,
                CallerID,
                signal
            }
            socketRef.current.emit("call partner",payload);
            
        });
        peer.on("stream",handleStream);
        //peer.on("data",handleData);
        return peer;
    }

    const addPeer = (CallerID,insignal,stream) =>{
        console.log("inside addpeer");
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator:false,
            trickle:false,
            stream
        });
        peer.on("signal",(signal)=>{
            console.log("inside peer");
            const payload={
                CallerID,
                signal
            }
            socketRef.current.emit("accept call",payload);
        });
        peer.on("stream",handleStream);
        
        peer.signal(insignal);
        
        return peer;
    }
    

    return(
        <Container>
            <LeftRow>
                <Video autoPlay ref={userRef} />
                <Video autoPlay ref={partnerRef} />
            </LeftRow>
            <RightRow>
                
            </RightRow>
        </Container>
    );
    

}

export default Room;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);
server.listen(5000);

const rooms={};

io.on('connection',(socket)=>
{
    console.log("Connected");
    
    socket.on("join room",(roomID)=>{
        console.log("User here");
        if(rooms[roomID])
            rooms[roomID].push(socket.id);
        else
            rooms[roomID]=[socket.id];
        const otherUser = rooms[roomID].find(id => id!==socket.id);
        
        socket.emit("other user",otherUser);

    });
    socket.on("call partner",(incoming)=>{
        console.log("call partner from server");
        const payload={
            CallerID:incoming.CallerID,
            signal:incoming.signal
        }
        io.to(incoming.PartnerID).emit("caller signal", payload);
    });
    socket.on("accept call",(incoming)=>{
        console.log("accept call");
        io.to(incoming.CallerID).emit("callee signal",incoming.signal);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, I was using version 9.7.2 of simple-peer. It seems to have a bug, so bringing the version down to 9.6.2 fixed the error.